# Софт для удаленного управления

Tags: поиск-программ, remote-access

Есть коммерческие Teamviewer и Anydesk, но там нехватает проброса консоли. Есть tmate, но там не хватает проброса портов. Nomachine - нужно знать ip:port которые прокинул клиент. А Гуакомоле бесполезен если машина и сервер в разных сетях.

tmate, но с пробросом туннелей отлично бы подошел.

Comment: Пробросить порт через Teamviewer/Anydesk и подключиться к ssh?)

Comment: тим валится часто. энидеском так и сижу) вот только бы ещё хедлес режим на нем сделать. без икса на вт соединение не устанавливается.

Comment: Для Linux? можно использовать parallel-ssh one-ssh или что-то подобное, для массовых раскаток через консоль. А управление экраном через VNC

Comment: parallel-ssh - не в ту сторону.  one-ssh не знаю что такое. а VNC за натом